# Update MySQL field; condition = string field between two numbers

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1292

I am trying to update a field's value if a string column is between two numbers.

```
UPDATE SAMPLE.EXAMPLE 
SET modNum = CONCAT(modNum,"26")
WHERE modNum NOT LIKE '%26%' 
  AND (procKey BETWEEN 90000 AND 99123 OR procKey = 77444);
```

Unfortunately I get an error:

> Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '4123F   '

I am surprised because when I do a select I get the expected results.

```
SELECT *
FROM SAMPLE.EXAMPLE 
WHERE modNum NOT LIKE '%26%' 
  AND (procKey BETWEEN 90000 AND 99123 OR procKey = 77444);
```

Create table statement:

```
'CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `modNum` char(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `procKey` char(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

Sample Data:

```
INSERT INTO `SAMPLE`.`EXAMPLE` (`modNum`, `procKey`) VALUES ('42', '99001');
INSERT INTO `SAMPLE`.`EXAMPLE` (`modNum`, `procKey`) VALUES ('42', '9900f');
```

What can I do to update the columns given my conditions?

---

---

To me it looks like a bug. The best I can come up with is to check if the value of procKey is an integer by using regular expressions. I changed my UPDATE statement to be:

```
UPDATE SAMPLE.EXAMPLE 
SET modNum = CONCAT(modNum,"26") 
WHERE modNum NOT LIKE '%26%' 
    AND procKey REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' 
    AND (procKey BETWEEN 90000 AND 99123 
        OR procKey = 77444);
```

Please, let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: What is the datatype of `modNum`?

Comment: Thank you @jcho360. If it is a bug, which I could believe it is, do you have any suggested ways around it?

Comment: do u have another DB where you can make a test? what is you mysql version?

Comment: @ypercube Whoops, I meant to mention that in my question. I have now added it to the end of my question.

Comment: @jcho360 version is 5.5.15. What kind of test?

Comment: try to make a backup of the example table and test it in another version of Mysql, to see if your query is working ok and its a Mysql -v 5.5.15 issue

Comment: Are there any UPDATE triggers defined for this table? Can you also add in the question, the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: Any reason you are using "string column" for numbers?

Comment: @ypercube no triggers and I have added the create statement to my question

Comment: @njk Yes I am using string because the values are not always numbers. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like a bug. The best I can come up with is to check if the value of procKey is an integer by using regular expressions. I changed my UPDATE statement to be:

```
UPDATE SAMPLE.EXAMPLE 
SET modNum = CONCAT(modNum,"26") 
WHERE modNum NOT LIKE '%26%' 
    AND procKey REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' 
    AND (procKey BETWEEN 90000 AND 99123 
        OR procKey = 77444);
```

Please, let me know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE SAMPLE.EXAMPLE
SET modNum = CONCAT(modNUM,"26") 
WHERE modNum NOT LIKE '%26%' 
  AND (procKey BETWEEN 90000 AND 99123 OR procKey = 77444);
```

Comment: Thanks for the CONCAT suggestion, I think I will do that . . . but that is not where my problem is.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me, so I', pretty sure it has to be some bug.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `example` (
    ->   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `modNum` char(4) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `procKey` char(8) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> UPDATE EXAMPLE                                                               
-> SET modNum = CONCAT(modNum,"26")
    -> WHERE modNum NOT LIKE '%26%' 
    ->   AND (procKey BETWEEN 90000 AND 99123 OR procKey = 77444);
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'SOF.EXAMPLE' doesn't exist
mysql> UPDATE example 
    -> SET modNum = CONCAT(modNum,"26")
    -> WHERE modNum NOT LIKE '%26%' 
    ->   AND (procKey BETWEEN 90000 AND 99123 OR procKey = 77444);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.5.9     |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO `example` (`modNum`, `procKey`) VALUES ('42', '99001');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `example` (`modNum`, `procKey`) VALUES ('42', '9900f');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> UPDATE example  SET modNum = CONCAT(modNum,"26") WHERE modNum NOT LIKE '%26%'    AND (procKey BETWEEN 90000 AND 99123 OR procKey = 77444);
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 2

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                      |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '9900f   ' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '9900f   ' |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: BTW, in my Version, EXAMPLE != example, so check the lowercase and uppercase just in case

Comment: What values did you populate procKey with? Make sure it has a mixture with some fields being integers and others being mixed.

Comment: it's a empty table but still, if you want go to pastie.org and give me some data to populate the table

Comment: The error doesn't happen on an empty table. Try the supplied data that I have added to my question.

Comment: In my DB, it works but it throw a warnings, eve I did the Select Command and I received the same warning.